# JSON Parsing Issue When There are special Character

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON structure, which i want to parse in JS, but because of some special character i am getting invalid token error  and it cos of special character in protocol name which is making the JSON invalid. can anybody help me out in this? is there any way to handle this ?

JsFiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/G5umj/

Javascript:

```
var new_var = '{"ERRMSG":"","REPORT_NAME":"MS_SRA_VISIT_LP","QUERY":{"COLUMNS":["col1"],"DATA":[{"V1-6441-2013-12":{"PROTOCOL_NAME":"Full Protocol AFTER FIXING ISSUE\\ K1\" K2\"\"\"\"  \"\'\' K3","AUDIT_COMPANY":[{"Golder":{"auditors":[{"NAME":"Sabrina moore"}]}}]}}],"summary":[]}}';

var new_J = JSON.parse(new_var);
```

Comment: Json is invalid, Parse your json [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: "some errors"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Why do you have a JSON text embedded in a JavaScript string expressed as a string literal in the first place?

Comment: Invalid Token, its cos of Special Character in Protocol Name, is there any way i can handle it in JS?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak — The JavaScript string is invalid. We can't trivially get the JSON in order to run it through a parser.

Comment: @Quentin lookint at jsonlit, why does `"` require one slash  while `'` requires 2 ?  (which solves the problem actually)

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Some things need escaping in JSON. Some things need escaping in the JavaScript string. The JSON escape character is one of the things that needs escaping in a JavaScript string.

Comment: @Quentin  ? I  know but why id does not fail with `\"` while it fails with `\'` ?

Comment: ``\'`` doesn't cause it to fail: http://jsfiddle.net/HJ9Hm/

Comment: @RoyiNamir — You edited the question to include some JSON that is, at best, guesswork as to what the contents of the JavaScript string is supposed to be. I've rolled it back because the problem being expressed (and the errors described) are with the JavaScript, not the JSON itself.

Comment: @Quentin edited ???? No I just formatted it ! ( and If I remove the `\'` - it doesn fail at jsonlint)

Comment: @RoyiNamir — The question had a JavaScript string. You provided a JSON text. That isn't formatting. (If the JavaScript string was a valid string, then it would be reasonable to extract the JSON from it, but it isn't).

Comment: @Quentin - Maybe I don't get your point. I just took the content of the string to see if it's valid json and it failed at `\'` thats all. I think we can be sure that the data between `var a='{....}'` suppose to be json.

Comment: @RoyiNamir — You didn't take "the content of the string" because ``\`` has special meaning **in a JavaScript string literal** and you didn't convert those in the way that a JavaScript parser would.

Comment: @Quentin Another thought : why it fails in the first one while in the other it success ? ( that's my point actually)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/S9vOG.jpg

Comment: JSON doesn't allow single quotes to be escaped (and they never need to be escaped because they aren't characters with any special meaning), but that's irrelevant because the only escaped single quotes in the question are escaped in the JavaScript string, not the resulting JSON.

Comment: @Quentin it is strange cuz JS do ignore unnecessary escapes : (`'\a\c'=='ac'`).... and so : (`'\a\''=="a'"`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir — JSON isn't JavaScript, even if it is inspired by some JS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It should be ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5umj/2/)):

```
var new_var = '{"ERRMSG":"","REPORT_NAME":"MS_SRA_VISIT_LP","QUERY":{"COLUMNS":["col1"],"DATA":[{"V1-6441-2013-12":{"PROTOCOL_NAME":"Full Protocol AFTER FIXING ISSUE\\\\ K1\\" K2\\"\\"\\"\\"  \\"\'\' K3","AUDIT_COMPANY":[{"Golder":{"auditors":[{"NAME":"Sabrina moore"}]}}]}}],"summary":[]}}';

var new_J = JSON.parse(new_var);
```

`'" \" "'` – this is escaping of `"` in single quotes, but `'" \\" "'` is escaping of escaping in double quotes :)